# Perspective image-upload C# method

Tags: c#, methods, perspective, image-upload

I'm currently working on an Upload function in my ASP.NET Web Application which I need to perspective the picture before I save it.

Ex.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAM2s.png

I know I can do it with CSS3 and jQuery on my frontend, but I would like it to be the actual picture which looks like this when it gets uploaded.

I hope some of you guys can help me with a C# method to do this under a picture upload.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add new item:
public struct Vertex
{
   public double X, Y, Z;
   public Vertex(double x, double y, double z)
   {
      this.X = x;
      this.Y = y;
      this.Z = z;
   }
}
//In page's code add:
public PointF GetPerspectiveProjectionOf(double x, double y, double z)
{
   double size = 2.0 * z * Math.Tan(Math.PI / 4.0);
   return new PointF((float)(x / size + 0.5), (float)(1.0 - y / size - 0.5));
}
public Image Upload(Image image, double distance, double spinInDegrees, int widthOfNewImage, int heightOfNewImage)
{
   double spinInRadians = spinInDegrees * Math.PI / 180.0;
   var v1 = new Vertex((-image.Width / 2.0) * Math.Cos(spinInRadians), image.Height / 2.0, (-image.Width / 2.0) * Math.Sin(spinInRadians));
   var v2 = new Vertex(-v1.X, v1.Y, -v1.Z);
   var v3 = new Vertex(v2.X, -v2.Y, v2.Z);
   var v4 = new Vertex(v1.X, -v1.Y, v1.Z);
   v1.Z += distance;
   v2.Z += distance;
   v3.Z += distance;
   v4.Z += distance;
   if (v1.Z < 0.0 || v2.Z < 0.0 || v3.Z < 0.0 || v4.Z < 0.0)
   {
       throw new ArgumentException("You are heading too close to the spinned image! You should increase distance.", "distance");
   }
   Image img = new Bitmap(widthOfNewImage, heightOfNewImage);
   Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img);
   graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
   SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Empty);
   Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)image;
   for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
   {
      for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
      {
          var x1 = v1.X + x * Math.Cos(spinInRadians);
          var z1 = v1.Z + x * Math.Sin(spinInRadians);
          var y1 = v1.Y - y;
          var x2 = v1.X + (x + 1) * Math.Cos(spinInRadians);
          var z2 = v1.Z + (x + 1) * Math.Sin(spinInRadians);
          var y2 = v1.Y - y - 1;
          var p1 = GetPerspectiveProjectionOf(x1, y1, z1);
          var p2 = GetPerspectiveProjectionOf(x2, y1, z2);
          var p3 = GetPerspectiveProjectionOf(x2, y2, z2);
          var p4 = GetPerspectiveProjectionOf(x1, y2, z1);
          p1.X *= widthOfNewImage;
          p1.Y *= heightOfNewImage;
          p2.X *= widthOfNewImage;
          p2.Y *= heightOfNewImage;
          p3.X *= widthOfNewImage;
          p3.Y *= heightOfNewImage;
          p4.X *= widthOfNewImage;
          p4.Y *= heightOfNewImage;
          sb.Color = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
          graphics.FillPolygon(sb, new PointF[] { p1, p2, p3, p4 });
      }
   }
   sb.Dispose();
   graphics.Dispose();
   return img;
}
```

Verify that you are:

```
using System.Drawing;
//AND
using Systen.Drawing.Drawing2D;
```

namespaces, and of course that you have added reference to System.Drawing.
You can play with this method and give any distance and angle until you are satisfied from the result. You can use another editors, like photoshop, to crop the result image if necessary and then you can use it for any of your purposes. I tested it at home before posting this answer and at last it worked great for me. There are no reasons why it shouldn't work for you too. Hope this helps and match your request. Have fun with it!